# Beginner having a problem with matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, import

I am using the book Python Crash Course as a textbook. I was doing pretty well until I tried to use the Matplotlib library. The book gave the following command to install the library:

*python -m pip install --user matplotlib*

I entered this in the terminal window in Pycharm (the IDE I am using). It appeared to work, in that I got a series of messages indicating that files were being downloaded and installed on my computer. However when I attempted to import matplotlib.pyplot into an example piece of code I was trying to write, I got a *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'*

I assumed that the downloaded module went to the wrong directory, so I searched my hard drive to find a file or folder named matplotlib. I found several folders in different locations, but when I tried copying them into folders where I knew Pycharm could find it, it didn't seem to help. Can someone please clue me in to how I can use this module.

I am using windows 10 on an MS Surface 6.

Comment: If you're having issues you can always install a .whl package directly. You can use https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib for instance and just know what Python version and architecture you'er on. But it's also possible you need to restart the IDE as it may not automatically reload these folders.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but as I said, I am a beginner. I haven't the faintest idea how to use these WHL files, nor do I know which one(s) to download. I have tried closing and reopening pycharm (my IDE) several times, no help. I even tried using Jupyter Notebook with no success.

I just attempted to reinstall the matplotlib module using the command line. After doing so I found that I was able to run my code successfully using Sublime Text. Still can't run it from Pycharm.

Comment: PyCharm most likely isn't able to figure out where it's installed then or you might have multiple versions of python installed and it might be referencing files associated with a different version of Python

Comment: PyCharm can be a little confusing to work with around modules and installing libraries. I believe PyCharm creates a new environment for every project, so you might have installed it to your system and PyCharm can't find it in the current environment it's running in, or vice versa. You said you entered that in the terminal window. What happens if you start a Python terminal session in that window and try to import matplotlib? Have you been able to install any other libraries? Finally, you might try the shorter command `pip install matplotlib`, which would install it to an active environment.

Comment: It's really odd. If I try to import from the terminal window of pycharm, I get the following error message:
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

Comment: Thanks for your help @japhyr. I tried the shorter install and got the same error message as before. I also found that if I ran the import line from the cmd window, it worked fine, even though the starting directory (c:\users\randy) was the same as in the pycharm terminal window.

Comment: @randytoad, does this resource help? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

Comment: Thanks again @japhyr. I tried the method for adding the package in that resource. Unfortunately it didn't help. The most recent time I tried to add the matplotlib package from the package installer, I got the following error message:

Comment: The error message was as follows:
src/checkdep_freetype2.c(5): fatal error C1189: #error:  "FreeType version 2.3 or higher is required. You may set the MPLLOCALFREETYPE environment variable to 1 to let Matplotlib download it."
Of course, I don't know how to set MPLLOCALFREETYPE environment to 1. I have tried just about everything, and have decided to just use Sublime Text. It's not as powerful as Pycharm, but I can get it to work. Thanks again for your help.